# ¿Como accedo a variables de otra clase en python?

Tags: python, visual-studio, programación-funcional

Buen dia, quisiera acceder a variables de otra clase de python segun se hacerlas globales es hacer el codigo mal, aun asi intente de este modo pero igual manera no se como acceder a ellas adjunto mi codigo para visualizar de una mejor manera mi duda.
El codigo siguiente esta en una clase digamos clase 2, justo donde esta el comentario es que tengo la duda.

```
def ejecutar(self, columna):
    actual = self.primero

    contador = 0
    while actual:
        if contador == int(columna):
            if actual.dato == 1:
                listaFilas()#al entrar aca quiero cambiar los valores de la varible de otra clase 
            actual.dato = 1
            break
        contador += 1
        actual = actual.siguiente
```

Y el codigo siguiente esta en otra clase digamos clase1, las variables fila, columna e infectados es lo que quiero acceder en la clase de arriba o en la otra clase2.

```
fila = 0
columna = 0
infectadas = 0

class Nodo(object):
    def __init__(self, siguiente=None, anterior=None):
        self.listaDeColumnas = listaColumnas()#Tiene otras listas
        self.siguiente = siguiente
        self.anterior = anterior
```

en la primera foto esta mi primera clase
[image: Imagen1]

Esta seria mi otra clase
[image: Imagen2]

Estoy trabajando con listas Doblemente Enlazadas y la verdad me confundo un poco los nodos entonces por ello me tope con esta duda gracias y espero entiendan mi duda.

Comment: Las variables `fila`, `columna` e `infectadas` no pertenecen a ninguna clase, son variables globales del módulo `ListaFilas.py` ¿Lo que deseas es cambiar variables desde un script a otro?

Comment: Si lo que quiero es cambiar los datos que guardan las variables del módulo o script clase1 pero desde cualquier otro modulo o script clase 2

Comment: Podes crear, modificar, eliminar y obtener las variables globales de un modulo usando atributos. Por ejemplo mimodulo.a = 1, donde mimodulo es un modulo, crea la variable global a en mimodulo y la establece en 1.